# Java classpath related

Tags: java

I had two classes

```
package xcom;
public class A { }

package xcom;
public class B extends A {  }
```

The directory structure is :

- foo/test/xcom/A.java
- foo/test/xcom/B.java

I first compiled A.java, then deleted the A.java file so that xcom now contains
B.java and A.class, now finally  using again xcom as current directory I compiled 
B.java using command 'javac B.java' and B.java was produced in same directory, this 
is where I got confused, because by default javac command does not search current 
directory for class , so why does this program compiled.Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javac` compiles `B.java` only. It doesn't re-compile `A.java`. Instead it uses the compiled version: `A.class`, which `javac` expects to exist in your `CLASSPATH`. Since `B.java` compiles just fine, your `CLASSPATH` is apparently set up correctly. The existence of `A.java` is irrelevant.

Here is some [more information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: Whether you set it or not, it is, at the very least, implicitly set up correctly, because `B.java` compiled just fine. Perhaps it is only looking in the same directory from which you started your command prompt. I can't really say, because I don't know your specific setup.

Comment: and ur saying that it uses A.class so does it mean that javac command do search the current directory by default for class files.

Comment: If, when you execute `javac`, the current working directory is `.../foo/test/xcom/`, then yes. This is the same as when the `CLASSPATH` is set up and contains `.` as an element.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect that's true. Here's documentation on [`javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), and the [`CLASSPATH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html). The information you seek is likely in there.

Comment: "if we give him any other classpath in command-line then it is not able to find class in the current directory but only searches in the specified classpath". If you put `.` into the classpath, then it does indeed search the current directory. That is, the directory from which `javac` was invoked.

Comment: just one last thing, i checked everything again on my command prompt and guess what , yes everything I said above is true, and thatz how it works, now I completely got it.again thanks a lot and good bye!!